# impose order (not sorting) using comparator on a wrapper class of a list in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, comparator, comparable

I have a class, person. it has Age, Name, Height, etc.
I am creating a class called PersonCollection which is a wrapper of a list (an ArrayList).

I will like to be able to compare Person objects using the PersonCollection class, Which means, I don't want to make the Person class implement the Comparable interface, I would like the PersonCollection to implement the Comparator interface.

I have having trouble doing that. I have implemented the compare method but still when I compare Person Objects it doesn't work.

for example this code gives me an error (people is an ArrayList

```
public void insert (Person p){
    for(int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++){
        if (people.get(i) > p){
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to use Comparator for sorting, this is different. 
I am fully aware of other possible and maybe better solutions (any priority queue class or some sort of sortedset classes)

I wish to do that for ArrayList for a specific reason and I kindly ask you to base your solutions on this instead of suggest other Data structures.

Comment: Since Java doesn't have operator overloading (and your `Person` class doesn't even implement `Comparable`), it's no surprise that you can't use `>` to compare objects.

Comment: So shouldn't Comparator solve this ? PersonCollection implements a Comperator<Person> according to the two Person's age for example.

Comment: I don't see why a *collection* should be a comparator, but if you want to abuse design, sure thing, write a `compare()` method and implement it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom `Comparator` and use the `compare(a, b)` method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-

Your code would look like

```
if (myComparator.compare(people.get(i), p) > 0 ) {
```

Comment: Ok so this doesn't really use the compare function as default but I guess that there isn't any other option so this is good enough for me .

Comment: @NotSure why can't you implement it in a clean and proper way? School project I guess?

Comment: Job interview task that asks for an implementations of a PersonCollection (saying not to actual implement a Person class, just use it as interface)

Comment: Sometimes you can't modify the class in order to make it `Comparable`, or other times you might not want to, or you might need more than one way to compare or sort the data - therefore `Comparator` is a good alternative to `Comparable`.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description you have a Wrapper class like this?

```
public class People implements List<Person>, Comparator<Person>{
    /* methods */
}
```

so if you want to really use comparator interface, then you would have to do it like this:

```
public void insert (Person p){
    for(int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++){
        if (people.compare(people.get(i),p)){ // because people implements Comparator
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

which *should* (not too sure though) work.

But i would highly recommend not to use this and think about something better, as a class should not be a comparator and a list (because both interfaces should be used for completly different reasons).

A better approach would be to make `Person` implement `Comparable`, and then sort according to that

Comment: What I ended up doing is having a PersonCollection that has an ArrayList<Person> property called people and also a Comparator property that I get from a factory (the factory gives me a comparator according to my choosing of comparing with age,name,id, etc...) and ended up using @vikingsteve approch. I know that a Comparable on Person is the most obvious but I was tasked not to implement this that way

Answer (score 1):

Below is a piece of code where you can see a custom comparator is making an age comparison on Person object's age attribute.

```
   public class TestCompare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person1 = new Person(45, "Tom");
        Person person2 = new Person(12, "Sarah");
        Person person3 = new Person(34, "Michael");
        Person person4 = new Person(33, "Donald");
        Person person5 = new Person(65, "timothy");
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        people.add(person1);
        people.add(person2);
        people.add(person3);
        people.add(person4);
        people.add(person5);

        CustomComparator comparator=new CustomComparator();

        for (Person p : people) {
            System.out.println(comparator.compare(p, new Person(55, "James")));
        }
    }

}

class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Person> {



    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return o1.getAge().compareTo(o2.getAge());
    }


}

class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    public Person(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    private Integer age;
    private String name;

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.getAge().compareTo(o.getAge());
    }

}
```